# urxvt not loading xft font from ~/.Xdefaults

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, x11, fonts, urxvt

Some basic details:

```
archlinux 3.9.3-1
xmonad 0.11
urxvt 9.18
```

I can get urxvt to load my desired font manually using:

```
urxvt -fn "xft:Ubuntu Mono"
```

However, I'm unable to get this font to load through ~/.Xdefaults - Here's what I have at the moment:

```
Xft*dpi: 96
Xft*antialias: true
Xft*rgba: rgb
Xft*hinting: true
Xft*hintstyle: hintslight

URxvt*transparent: true
URxvt*shading: 40
URxvt*saveLines: 12000
URxvt*foreground: White
URxvt*background: Black
URxvt*scrollBar: false
Urxvt*font: xft:Ubuntu Mono
Urxvt*boldFont: xft:Ubuntu Mono
```

All other urxvt settings load fine, except the font. I've tried many different combinations like: `xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=14:style=regular` etc, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults`, `xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults`, and restarting X entirely. I've also tried these settings in ~/.Xresources, however urxvt seems to ignore those settings entirely. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `URxvt` instead of `Urxvt`. It's case sensitive.

```
URxvt*font: xft:Ubuntu Mono
URxvt*boldFont: xft:Ubuntu Mono
```

Comment: Jee wizz.. I feel silly. Thanks, thats exactly what is was.